# R function to find best and worst level of a variable

Tags: r

I am using "diamonds" dataset from "tidyverse" package. In the 'diamonds' dataset 'color' is a categorical variable with 7 levels and I need to find which is the best level and which is the worst level of 'color'. So here is my codes:

```
sort(diamonds$color, decreasing = TRUE)[1] #to find the best level
sort(diamonds$color, decreasing = FALSE)[1] #to find the worst level
```

I am not confident in my codes. Could someone check if my codes are correct for me? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Define `best` and `worst` by it's level(as `color` is ordinal categorical variable),

You may use `levels()` as

```
levels(diamonds$color)[1]
tail(levels(diamonds$color), 1)
```

where order is `Levels: D < E < F < G < H < I < J`